# MS Access error - Division by zero when executing query

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am using a Crosstab query to calculate the percentage from a pair of numbers and a Make query to put the result into a different table.

Source data is something like this:

```
ITEMS    |PAIRS    |VAL
Element1 |dividend |43
Element1 |divisor  |33
Element2 |dividend |65
Element3 |dividend |73 
Element4 |dividend |32
Element4 |divisor  |23
Element3 |divisor  |49
```

PLEASE NOTE: In a real situation, it is entirely possible that one of the two elements is missing (the divisor part of Element2, in this case).

Here is how I made the Crosstab query (named QCross) to overcome the 'Overflow' error.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(TRawData.Val) AS SumOfVAL
SELECT TRawData.ITEMS, IIf(IsError(Sum(IIf(TRawData.[PAIRS]='dividend', TRawData.[VAL],0))/Sum(IIf(TRawData.[PAIRS]='divisor',TRawData.[VAL],0))),0,Sum(IIf(TRawData.[PAIRS]='dividend',TRawData.[VAL],0))/Sum(IIf(TRawData.[PAIRS]='divisor',TRawData.[VAL],0))) AS MYRES
FROM TRawData
GROUP BY TRawData.ITEMS 
PIVOT TRawData.PAIRS;
```

And this is the Make query

```
SELECT QCross.ITEMS, QCross.MYRES INTO TOutcome
FROM QCross;
```

The Crosstab query is working well, however I am dealing with a 'division by zero' error when the Make query is executed (!Run).

Can anyone help me to understand where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

You code is not fast to comprehend, but a generic method is to check if the divisor is zero and, if so, replace with, say, 0 and 1 for dividend and divisor respectively to obtain a valid division and a result of 0:

```
result = IIf(divisor = 0, 0, dividend) / IIf(divisor = 0, 1, divisor)
```